# angular 2 how to import custom function to component and service

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function like this

**myHelperNumber.js**

```
function myLittleBoy(){
  console.log('I see you)
}
```

How to use this function in User.js component or userSevicer.js service?

Comment: need to export it

Comment: yes, also need to export it first

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**myHelperFunction.ts**

```
export function myLittleBoy(){
  console.log('Hello World')
}
```

**RegisterComponent.ts**

```
import {myLittleBoy} from 'path to myhelperfunction.ts'
```

Comment: little cosmetic: console.log('I see you')

Comment: I've proposed the edit of this cosmetic change

Answer (score 2):

```
export function myLittleBoy(){
  console.log('I see you)
}



import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var myLittleBoy:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>',
})
export class AppComponent  { 

    constructor(private __jsmodel:JSmodelEvents){
        myLittleBoy();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import {myHelperNumber} from 'your path';
export class AppComponent{
   constructor(private helpNum: myHelperNumber){
      // Now you can use myLittleBoy function anywhere inside the AppComponent Class
      // Like below shown: 
      // this.helpNum.myLittleBoy();
   }
}
```

Make sure your myHelperNumber file is in exportable format.

Answer (score -2):

myHelperNumber.ts:

```
export const function myLittleBoy(){
  console.log('I see you)
}
```

Then in User.ts or userService.ts

```
import {myLittleBoy} from './myHelperNumber';
// and just use it in this class
```

Comment: did that, it says myHelperNumber was resolve to path bla bla... but --alowJs is not set

Comment: not by service but by component to another component as the above answer stated