# How to call function expression of javascript from angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

How to call function expression of JavaScript from angular 7?

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463368/calling-function-expression-from-external-javascript-file-within-angular4-compon?fbclid=IwAR2NSrUIcm6vrRuv895KHP-MXbYROuJ_oSzMsFAmEZhyBhSydHmsv7w1GCg)

here is my `test.js`:

```
'use strict';
var val = (function() {
    function launch() {
        console.log("val");
    };
    return {
        launch: launch
    };
})();
```

I wanna call launch method from Angular Typescript
I am trying as:

```
declare var val2: any;

ngOnInit() {
    val.launch();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 how to import custom function to component and service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438801/angular-2-how-to-import-custom-function-to-component-and-service)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: import external js file into component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to understand your question, but I'll have a shot:

The source code in Angular projects is composed of [ES modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/), ie functions and variables are passed from one file to another via imports and exports.

If you want to use `val` from `test.js` in `some.component.ts`, you might want to do that:

In `test.js`:

```
var val = /* ... */
export { val }
```

In `some.component.ts`:

```
import { val } from './test.js';

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    val.launch();
  }
}
```